# Cannot connect Heart Rate Device to Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, bluetooth-gatt

I'm trying to use a Windows Universal App to connect my Polar OH1 heart rate device to my Mac through Bluetooth GATT (it's dual booted Windows 10). I'm doing this in C++.

```
IAsyncOperation<DeviceInformationCollection^>^ deviceOp =
    DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService::GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids::HeartRate));
```

When I try to run this method it returns null, even though I added Bluetooth to the app manifest and have the Polar Oh1 paired to Windows 10.

Comment: Please try the official code sample(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario1_Discovery.xaml.cs) to see if you can discover your device.

Comment: You also could change the `GattServiceUuids::HeartRate` to `GattServiceUuids:: DeviceInformation` in your code to see if it will work.

Comment: I've been messing with it and I think one of the main reasons it's doing this is because when I pair it with Windows 10, it doesn't recognize it as a heart rate device. I checked in the Device Manager as well, and when I click on the Polar OH1, and then check the capabilities, it says that it is "00000080
CM_DEVCAP_SURPRISEREMOVALOK" which isn't promising.

Comment: If you do not pair it with windows, does it work?